# Expotar Banco de Dados SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados

Necessito exportar meu banco de dados *SQLite* para uma pasta do dispositivo na qual irá ser instalado, e toda vez que eu abrir o aplicativo, o arquivo *“.bd”* seja atualizado para que no final do mês eu possa convertê-lo para o Excel. Só preciso encontrar esse arquivo ou criá-lo porque minha aplicação não está criando uma pasta de arquivos ou um diretório no qual eu possar achar o *Data Base File* dela.

Gostaria de obter um código funcional para exportação desse banco, bem como o passo a passo, se possível, da estrutura deste código para eventuais erros.

Eis o meu banco de dados:

```
public class ProdutosBD extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABASE ="bdprodutos";
private  static final int VERSION = 1;

public ProdutosBD (Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE,null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String produto = "CREATE TABLE produtos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, matricula INTEGER, supervisao TEXT NOT NULL,  material TEXT NOT NULL, quantidade INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(produto);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String produto = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS produtos";
    db.execSQL(produto);
}
// aqui salva
public void salvarProduto(Produtos produto){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("matricula",produto.getMatricula());
    values.put("supervisao",produto.getSupervisao());
    values.put("material",produto.getMaterial());
    values.put("quantidade",produto.getQuantidade());

    getWritableDatabase().insert("produtos",null,values);
}
// metodo alterar concluído ? :D
public void alterarProduto(Produtos produto){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("matricula",produto.getMatricula());
    values.put("supervisao",produto.getSupervisao());
    values.put("material",produto.getMaterial());
    values.put("quantidade",produto.getQuantidade());

    String [] args = {produto.getId().toString()};
    getWritableDatabase().update("produtos",values,"id=?",args);

}

public void deletarProduto(Produtos produto){
    String [] args = {produto.getId().toString()};
    getWritableDatabase().delete("produtos","id=?",args);
}

// lista - mostrar

public ArrayList<Produtos> getLista(){
    String [] columns ={"id","matricula","supervisao","material","quantidade"};
    Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().query("produtos",columns,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    ArrayList<Produtos> produtos = new ArrayList<Produtos>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        Produtos produto = new Produtos();
        produto.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        produto.setMatricula(cursor.getInt(1));
        produto.setSupervisao(cursor.getString(2));
        produto.setMaterial(cursor.getString(3));
        produto.setQuantidade(cursor.getInt(4));

        produtos.add(produto);
    }
    return produtos;
}



}
```

Comment: Na constate `DATABASE` você pode colocar o caminho completo onde você quer salvar seu banco de dados, ex: `DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().concat("/database.db")`, porém é necessário ter a permissão `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Do modo que você está fazendo, o Android irá salvar o banco de dados em uma pasta interna e somente dispositivos com *root*, poderá acessar.

Comment: Ok Valdeir, muito obrigado. Vou tentar e retorno :D

Comment: Ok, mais uma dúvida amigo: como vou saber em qual pasta o "/bdprodutos.db" foi salvo?

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` retorna o caminho do cartão de memória. No exemplo acima, ele salva na raiz do cartão. Ou você pode usar [**Environment.html.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

Comment: Existe um local específico onde colocar o arquivo apk na hora da instalação? Porque em relação ao código estou fazendo desta forma
DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().concat("Card\\Android\\data/bdprodutos.db") e não está dando certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na constate `DATABASE` você pode colocar o caminho completo onde você quer salvar seu banco de dados. Exemplo:

```
private static final String DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
            File.separator + "path" +
            File.separator + "to" +
            File.separator + "database.db";
```

Dessa forma seu banco de dados será criado em `/sdcard/path/to/database.db`

Comment: O problema é que essa constante recebendo "bdprodutos" como está no código, é chamada neste momento: 

public ProdutosBD (Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE,null, VERSION);
}

Ou seja, será armazenada necessariamente na constante DATABASE  o "bdprodutos" para que o app funcione. Assim, acredito que terei que atribuir dois valores para essa constante. Um para o SQLite em si ser criado no app, e outra para a exportação. É possível?